# App working on the Dev server, not working when deployed on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My App is doing following :
When the client connects, it checks the authentication (using Google accounts) and if not OK provides login link. Then it display a "loading..." message while the UI is loading and the initial needed data is fetched. Then it shows up.

My problem : Since the last deployment (minor UI changes) yesterday, the app does the authentication correctly, displays the loading message, and then hangs. The browser is not doing anything anymore, nor does my instance on GAE.

In the app logs I see the expected request being logged, e.g. requests for /, CSS file, scripts and static files (images etc..), and of course the authentication RPC request. All these run perfectly, without errors or exceptions. But then the app does just stop!

As the app perfectly does on the local development server, and as I don't have any error or exception to start the debugging with, I'm screaming for help!

Please not that I already tried all variants, beginning with clearing my datastore and my memcache, ending by completely deleting my app and creating a new one with a fresh new App ID, nothing helps.

As it runs correctly locally but not online, how can I find the bug?

Comment: *"I already tried all variants"*  Except the one that works.

Comment: Check network connections in your browser to see at what point the process stops. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: Chrome's developer tools? never heard before. Will give it a try tonight.

Comment: Your description is sufficiently vague that just about every App Engine app fits it. There's no way we can help you debug this with so little information. You say you made minor changes - what happens if you undo them? Does it start working again? What about if you create the simplest possible app that reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: I tried this before, but as the UI init is dependant from the datastore content, I could not really test the exact same use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem solved !

The Google Chrome Developer Tools helped me to see an Exception which I did not catch/handle on the client side. Therefore I did not see any error when trying the online app. One of my class's Constructor does some initialization work differently when in Prod or Development Environment, and I had a corner case related to UI init and datastore content in the case of Prod Environment.

- When developing, ALWAYS catch EVERY potential Exception, and develop minimal handling (instead of an empty catch() block, log the exception)
- Chrome Developer Tools helps a lot (thanks Peter !)